# How does ObservableCollection<T> implement INotifyPropertyChanged as protected?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

This is the definition for [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public interface INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

`ObservableCollection<T>` implements this...

```
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

When I tested this...

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I got the following error:

> Test does not implement interface member
>   'System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged'.
>   'Test.PropertyChanged' cannot implement an interface member because it
>   is not public.

How is this possible?

Comment: It is wrong question it is not protected it is implemented as private....!

Comment: @JenishRabadiya can you please elaborate?

Comment: PropertyChanged is private inside ObservableCollection just update title and question accordingly. protected is not possible for it.

Comment: look at here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,f63ea2601f5edbbb provided by Sriram Sakthivel in his answer below for reference.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya the point of the question was to determine how ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I was confused when I saw the protected virtual member however if you read the accepted answer - this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes that's true but I am just asking you to update question. It created misunderstanding in my mind..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface itself is implemented explicitly, with a protected event for classes to override

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // explicit interface implementation
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            PropertyChanged += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            PropertyChanged -= value;
        }
    }

    // protected virtual (for derived classes to override)   
    protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the protected [`PropertyChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms653376%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms668604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) provides an explicit interface implementation for the [`INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460458%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is lacking in your class (and not shown in your code snippet from `ObservableCollection<T>`).

You can read about [explicit interface implementation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).